# getting JSON from PhoneGap application ?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm trying to send a getJson call from my app to get an external JSON from PHP file. all i'm getting is a gray empty screen ? can anyone tell me what's the problem or at least how can i debug to get the problem 
[image: JSON]

here also attached the PHP file running !!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more Information . Try to debug using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) , This is available for both chrome and firefox and since your using html run it in your browser and see what you get.

Do console.log(data); and see what is being outputted in your firebugs console tab. You might be running into some cross domain issue too. Use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) jquery JOSNP to over come this. just put **data: jsonp** .

Hope this helps you , please provide more information.